# Is this a case of a parenthetical remark?

Tags: commas

"He finished it before his 20th birthday." Should I apply the rule about parenthetical remark here and put 20th between two commas or it's not thecase here?

Comment: _...or is it not the case here?_ No, '20th' doesn't seem parenthetical to me. It identifies which birthday you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

It could be parenthetical, but it probably isn't.

If you mean  "He finished before his birthday  (by the way it was his 20th birthday, but you don't need to know that)"  The you could put it in parenthesis. Use round brackets, not commas, in this case.

But usually, you want to tell people which birthday you are talking about. It is relevant information, so normally you wouldn't put 20th in round brackets. Or if it is irrelevant, then just omit it.

Answer (score 0):

"He finished it before his 20th birthday" is a fine sentence that any English speaker would understand, and there is nothing wrong with it.